# IBM Websphere Application Server installer error "Adding zip com.ibm.websphere.IHS.ihsonly_z_dist.all_x_y to repository failed"

Tags: websphere-8

While trying to install IBM Websphere Application Server developer edition though IBM Installation Manager, getting following issue:

```
The following errors were generated while installing.
    Adding zip com.ibm.websphere.IHS.ihsonly_z_dist.all_x_y to repository 
    C:\opt\jas\iap\IMshared failed.
Resumable download failed for: 
 C:\tmp1\was\IBM\WAS\8.5\repository\native\com.ibm.websphere.IHS.ihsonly_z_dist.all_x_y.zip.

'zip com.ibm.websphere.IHS.ihsonly_z_dist.all_x y' does not exist
```

I don't find com.ibm.websphere.IHS.ihsonly_z_dist.all_x_y.zip in the installable bundles

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Unless you really have to use traditional WebSphere Application Server, for development purposes, I'd strongly recommend WebSphere Liberty (https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/) or OpenLiberty (https://openliberty.io/downloads/) which are both much more developer friendly, and in most cases can be used to develop apps that will be deployed on traditional. And they are using archive unzip install instead of Installation Manager.

Comment: as per customer requirement, we are testing for this developer edition as well